# Best database option for analytics over a flat table

Tags: database, performance, analytics

I got this problem in a project I'm working in.

We have a simple table with simple data but extremely large (80 millions of records so far).

The main application of the client should show analytics data from that table in real time (this is, the user choose some filters and got the results back).

This is: one table (just 12 colums), very large and simple analytics over it.

Which can be the best service to get that perfomance and the cheaper one?

We've tried with MemSQL and it works fine but the license is expensive...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

80 million records is frankly not that much. Depending on your environment, you should be able to get adequate performance from a well-indexed MySQL database. It's free.

Answer (score 0):

MemSQL community edition is free (http://www.memsql.com/community/) and has no limits on data size or cluster size.  If you don't need high availably or more advance security features it can still be a good option for you.